# Explanation of foldr implementation in Foldable

Tags: haskell

Here is the implementaion of foldr :

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
foldr f z t = appEndo (foldMap (Endo #. f) t) z
```

The part that I don't understand is that `(#. f)` should provide an endofunction `x -> x`

e.g foldr (:) [4,5] [1,2,3]

```
foldr (:) [4,5] [1,2,3] = appEndo (foldMap (Endo #. (:)) [1,2,3]) [4,5]
                        = appEndo (((Endo #. (:)) 1) <> 
                                   ((Endo #. (:)) 2) <> 
                                   ((Endo #. (:)) 3) ) [4,5]
                        = ???
                        = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Could someone decompose that example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's *not* `(. f)`, it's `(Endo . f)`.

**`#.`** is just like **`.`** (for our purposes here), and `Endo` is just like any other function. For instance,

```
(Endo . (:)) 1 = Endo ((:) 1) = Endo (1:)    -- by definition of (.), (f . g) x = f (g x)
```

`(1:)` is indeed an endofunction, its type `Num a => [a] -> [a]` is a more specialized version of `b -> b`, so the expression `Endo (1:)` makes sense (or, "has a type", or "is a well typed expression" -- `Endo 1`, for example, is not).

So, if you accept that `foldMap f [a,b,c] = f a <> f b <> f c`,

```
foldr (:) [4,5] [1,2,3] = appEndo (foldMap (Endo #. (:)) [1,2,3]) [4,5]
                        = appEndo (((Endo #. (:)) 1) <> 
                                   ((Endo #. (:)) 2) <> 
                                   ((Endo #. (:)) 3) ) [4,5]
                        = ??
```

then, from this point on, it's just a straightforward application of the appropriate definitions / equations:

```
   -- #. is like . 
                        = appEndo (((Endo  . (:)) 1) <> 
                                   ((Endo  . (:)) 2) <> 
                                   ((Endo  . (:)) 3) ) [4,5]
   -- (f . g) x = f (g x)
   -- (Endo . g) x = Endo (g x)
                        = appEndo (( Endo  ((:)  1)) <> 
                                   ( Endo  ((:)  2)) <> 
                                   ( Endo  ((:)  3)) ) [4,5]
                        = appEndo (( Endo  (1 :)   ) <> 
                                   ( Endo  (2 :)   ) <> 
                                   ( Endo  (3 :)   ) ) [4,5]
   -- (Endo f) <> (End g) = Endo (f . g)
                        = appEndo (( Endo  (1 :)   ) <> 
                                   ( Endo ((2 :) . (3 :)) )) [4,5]
                        = appEndo (  Endo ((1 :) . ((2 :) . (3 :))) ) [4,5]
   -- appendo (Endo f) = f
                        =                 ((1 :) . ((2 :) . (3 :)))   [4,5]
                        =                  (1 :) (  (2 :) ( (3 :)     [4,5] ))
                        =                  (1 :     (2 :    (3 :      [4,5] )))
                        =                   1 :      2 :     3 :      [4,5] 
                        = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Answer (score 2):

> The part that I don't understand is that `(#. f)` that should provide an endofunction `x -> x`

Remember that Haskell functions are curried. So `f :: a -> b -> b` is a one-argument function which takes an `a` and returns an endomorphism `b -> b`. `Endo #. f` plumbs the result of `f`, which is a function `b -> b`, into `Endo`, which expects a function as an argument.

Here's how that works in detail:

First of all, note that `(#.)` is basically a synonym for `(.)`. So you have

```
foldr f z t = appEndo (foldMap (Endo . f) t) z
```

After [Skolemnising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem_normal_form) `a` and `b` (so `f :: A -> B -> B` for rigid types `A` and `B`), the expression `(. f)` has a type of

```
(. f) :: forall r. ((B -> B) -> r) -> A -> r
```

Setting `Endo :: forall a. (a -> a) -> Endo a` as `(.)`'s left argument, you get `r ~ Endo B`:

```
Endo . f :: A -> Endo B
```

And because `foldMap :: Monoid m => (a -> m) -> t a -> m`,

```
foldMap (Endo . f) :: Foldable t => t A -> Endo B
```

and the rest of the function writes itself.

---

That's how the types work out. Let's break down your example.

```
foldr (:) [1, 2, 3] [4, 5]
appEndo (foldMap (Endo . (:)) [1, 2, 3]) [4, 5]
appEndo (((Endo . (:)) 1) <> ((Endo . (:)) 2) <> ((Endo . (:)) 3) ) [4, 5]
appEndo (Endo (1:) <> Endo (2:) <> Endo (3:)) [4, 5]  -- beta reduce (.)
appEndo (Endo $ (1:) . (2:) . (3:)) [4, 5]  -- definition of (<>) for Endo
((1:) . (2:) . (3:)) [4, 5]  -- appEndo (Endo f) = f
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand how you are making these simplications to deduce that Endo . f :: A -> Endo B from (f :: a -> b -> b), that's probably the knowledge I'm missing, what are the rules ? can I find a place somewhere that explain how you do that ?

Comment: `(.) :: forall a b c. (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`. When giving `f` as `(.)`'s right argument, the type checker unifies `(a -> b)` with `(A -> B -> B)`, which gives you `a ~ A` and `b ~ B -> B`. (Remember that functions are curried.) In other words, `f` takes an `A` and returns a `B -> B`. `Endo` takes a `B -> B` and returns an `Endo B`. So `Endo . f` plumbs `f`'s return value (`B -> B`) into the `Endo` constructor, to give you `A -> Endo B`.

Comment: first I was applying f to the first argument (b->c) not the second one (a->b), so are you saying that #. f is the sectionning (. f) and not ((.) f) as I was thinking?

Comment: Then from that point, It's really how you play with that signature that I don't get...it seems like I can do some kind of factorization with these elements so I get this `((B -> B) -> r) -> (A -> (B -> B)) -> A -> r` then ((B -> B) -> r ) -> ( A -> ((B -> B) -> r) ) ..., but I don't get your result...

Comment: Yes. `Endo . f` means `(.) Endo f`; `(Endo .)` means `(.) Endo`; `(. f)` means `\k -> (.) k f`.

Comment: You're on the right track. Given `(.) :: forall a b c. (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`, you can pick `b ~ (B -> B)` to get `((B -> B) -> c) -> (a -> B -> B) -> a -> c`, which is what you've got. Then you can pick `c ~ Endo B` and `a ~ A` to get `((B -> B) -> Endo B) -> (A -> B -> B) -> A -> Endo B`. Then the first argument matches the type of `Endo` and the second matches the type of `f`.

Comment: holy... ok I see it now :-)

Comment: do you know a blog or something where all the knowdledge you've used is explained ?... substitution , factorization and then realizing that you can end with something like Endo (.) f -> A -> Endo B... and that result means Endo (.) f ~ A -> Endo B

Comment: Hmm, that's a good question... Personally speaking I don't think I learned how type inference works from any particular source, so I don't think I can point you anywhere specific. It's more just developing an innate sense for it, for which sadly there's no substitute for writing lots of code over a long period of time. (One minor correction: it's `Endo . f`, not `Endo (.) f`. The former is `(.)` applied to `Endo` and `f`, whereas the latter is `Endo` applied to `(.)` and `f` (which is of course ill-typed)).